# Why `ServiceAccount` exists, but there is no such entity for the regular human user?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, k8s-serviceaccount

When managing entities semantically connected with Kubernetes, it makes sense to let Kubernetes manage them. Kubernetes manages `ServiceAccount` as a resource kind, but does not have similar kinds for human users or groups.

I'm wondering what is the design decision behind this. I know that `ServiceAccount` gets a token generated on creation that is used for further access, and for accessing a cluster as a human user, you need a config file with a public key signed with Kubernetes's CA.

It seems inconsistent, why not create similar resource kinds, say, `HumanAccount` or `Account` and supply a public key on creation (public key is kind of safe to store even in plain test in a yaml manifest), so that Kubernetes signs it and from that point on, accepts connections from the user?

I know that Certificate Signing Requests need to be approved by the administrator. Maybe that is the reason?

Any hints or insights appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually are [`User`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-example) entities in RBAC, but kubernetes delegates the instantiation of those to either [the `CN` field of mTLS authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#x509-client-certs), or [the `sub` claim of OIDC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#openid-connect-tokens), or in a very customized situation [one can provide that via HTTP headers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#authenticating-proxy)

Comment: Could you please expand your answer a bit - why is this design decision better than to allow the actual human user to transparently manage `User` manifest files?

Comment: I'm merely a consumer of k8s, not one of the original authors. Perhaps [the borg paper](https://research.google/pubs/pub43438/) can speak to your concerns